# ZeroMQ: command-response and status callbacks among UI, server and hetrogenous workers

Tags: design-patterns, asynchronous, architecture, zeromq, server

I am trying to set up an set of programs consisting of:

- a UI (or perhaps multiple UIs)
- a "server"
- a number of "workers".

The UI is how a user interacts with the system, the server does processing and marshalling, and the workers handle a wide range of hardware devices. Additionally, any number of these elements might be on different platforms (C, C++, Java, Python being the primary ones so far), and different physical machines. The workers are not interchangeable - the server knows which one can do what based on what the worker tells it about itself.

For example, imagining that the worker could make coffee, something like this:

- Worker A to server: "Hi, I'm a coffee machine and I'm ready to go"
- Server to UI: "Hi, I have a coffee machine here"
- UI to server (some time later): "User wants a coffee now, since you have a machine"
- Server to UI: "Working on that. Your order number is #42"
- Server to Worker A: "Coffee please"
- Worker A to server: "Coming right up"
- Worker A to server (some time later): "Here you go"
- Server to UI: "Coffee order #42 for you!"

I am not expecting a huge amount of traffic - maybe a few hundred packets a second at worst, and generally much less. Threading within each program is not a problem, unless the communication sockets are all tied up waiting for responses!

I was planning to use ZeroMQ to organise all of this, and I have a rudimentary REQ-REQ lockstep working between the server and the workers, and between the UI and server. However, the synchronous nature of this doesn't seem to work well when a hardware device could take a long time to complete what was asked of it.

It also doesn't seem to allow me to do something like have the server notify the UI about changes, and workers notify the server about their status changes, without setting up a second port on each link.

Does ZeroMQ (or another MQ, even) have a way to handle this kind of set-up?